# VirtualBox PXE Boot using PCnet-FAST III - Windows 7 driver required?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, wds

I'm using WDS to deploy a windows 7 image that I've captured.

Unfortunately, the AMD PCnet-FAST III is not recognised by windows 7 with VirtualBox.

Can anyone help me find a driver and or suggest another NIC to use with VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [NDIS5 Driver for Microsoft Windows](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/dynamicDetails.aspx?ListID=b7383048-1ac6-4dd5-9f0e-087bb719e48e&ItemID=476&lang=us) driver?

If you have trouble getting it into the VM, use something like `genisoimage` to generate an ISO you can mount in VirtualBox.

Comment: It has installed on my windows 7 vm (windows 7 isn't stated as supported), thanks! here's hoping this alleviates my WDS deployment woes!

Comment: PS, i'm on a mac so I made an ISO out of the folder since I don't have any shared folders configured with my VirtualBox yet :)

Comment: It's indeed not listed as supported but worked for me ;-).